# Pass Lines of Code as an Argument in C

Tags: c, parameter-passing

I'm working on a project in which I'm on a fairly strict word limit (I'm not 100% certain what qualifies as a word).

I'm looking to pass lines of code into a function as an argument, I've seen this done in JavaScript but I cannot find anything on it in C.

This is about what I'm looking for:

```
void onTime(int a, Code myCode) {
    if(timer == a) {
        //run myCode
    }
}
```

And I could use it something like this:

```
onTime(45, {
    //code
});
```

Is there a way in C that I can do something like this?

Comment: You can't do this in C, and I don't see how this would result in significantly shorter code. Maybe function pointers may help. What problem are you _actually_  trying to resolve?

Comment: These are nonsense requirements. Passing lines of code as argument is similarly, nonsense. You can use function pointers etc but not with the rationale of "saving word limit". The single most important quality in engineering is perhaps to be sceptical and question requirements that don't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin It's for a competition which has a very short 'word' limit. Instead of having a lot of if statements (taking up a lot of my words) I can save >1 word per call.

Comment: Sounds like you rather need to use loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C doesn't allow inline code (referred to as lambda expressions in other languages) to be passed around.  What you can do however is pass a pointer to an existing function.

```
//  typedef for a function that takes no arguments and returns void
typedef void (*ftype)(void);

void func_to_run(void)
{
    ...
}

void onTime(int a, ftype code) {
    if(timer == a) {
        code();
    }
}
```

You could then call it like this:

```
ontime(45, func_to_run);
```

If you want the function to be packaged with a set of values that it uses, similarly to C++ classes which have member functions which can access member variables, that involves some trickery.

Here's an example of how you might do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*ftype)(int, int);

struct c {
    int a;
    int b;
    ftype add_func;
    ftype sub_func;
};

#define ADD(s) (s)->add_func((s)->a,(s)->b)
#define SUB(s) (s)->sub_func((s)->a,(s)->b)

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a-b;
}

void run(struct c *op)
{
    printf("add result=%d\n", ADD(op));
    printf("sub result=%d\n", SUB(op));
}

int main()
{
    struct c c1 = { 1, 2, add, sub };
    struct c c2 = { 3, 4, add, sub };
    struct c c3 = { 6, 1, add, sub };
    struct c c4 = { 9, 4, add, sub };

    run(&c1);
    run(&c2);
    run(&c3);
    run(&c4);
}
```

Here we define a struct `c` which contains function pointers for two functions and two other variables.

The macros `ADD` and  `SUB` are used to run the "member" functions of the struct and pass them the "private" members to use.  It hides the fact that the actual function being called is independent of the parameters being passed to it.

This code outputs:

```
add result=3
sub result=-1
add result=7
sub result=-1
add result=7
sub result=5
add result=13
sub result=5
```

Of course, once you start doing this you're (crudely) doing what C++ is doing and would probably be better off switching to C++ which is made for OOP and now supports lambdas.

Comment: Preferably, `ADD` and `SUB` should be inline functions rather than macros. Also, this is a poor example of how to do OO in C, since those struct members are clearly not private at all. Private encapsulation in C is done through opaque type/opaque pointers and not as in this example.

Comment: @Lundin This was meant to be a simple example of how "members" can access other "members".  A full example with opaque pointers would involve creating additional constructor-like functions in a manner similar to above and the use of additional source/header files.

Comment: Indeed, but you make a recommendation to use C++ instead, based on this example code.

Comment: @dbush thank you, this works. I'm familiar with C++ so, given the choice, I would be using that. However, this is for a competition and there are very strict rules, using C is one of them.